# Importar base de datos mysql a phpmyadmin error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

he seguido varios tutoriales en youtube, entro a la carpeta de xampp mysql data y abro la carpeta de mi base de datos pero en los tutoriales que he visto en esa carpeta deberia aparecer la base de datos con extension de sql pero a mi me aparecen tres archivos 
uno .frm, .ibd y .opt al importar me marca error, que es lo que hago mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que pasa es que estas exportando la base de datos desde la raiz de xampp y no desde phpmyadmin donde te genera un .sql ya sea de la base de datos o de los registros.

si quieres el .sql tedrias que entrar a local, despues te vas a la base de datos a exportar y de ahi te vas donde dice exportar y presionas continuar y te descargara el archivo para importar a otro lado.

Comment: ah y hay que aclarar que el metodo con los tres archivos solo sirve entre locales ya que solo es pasar la carpeta donde se encuentran los 3 archivos a algun otra pc con xampp o wampp en su respectiva carpeta donde estan las bases de datos y aparecera la base de datos una vez colocada.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes acceso a una consola de **Unix** puedes ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
mysqldump -uUSUARIO -pPASSWORD nombre_basededatos > archivo.sql
```

Si la base de datos esta en un servidor externo agrega la siguiente **flag
-hIP/HOST**

```
mysqldump -uUSUARIO -pPASSWORD -h200.100.200.100 nombre_basededatos > archivo.sql
```

Suerte.